# How to play recommended videos in android app using youtube API?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have implemented YouTube API in android app and it worked fine. Now I want to see a list of recommended YouTube videos from a particular channel in android app. Is it possible to do so ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't play particular YouTube channel video if the permission is not given to public.
Also if you add that video links in your application then you will get rejected from playstore during review time due to violating the privacy policy.